# Pandas - Duplicate rows based on the last character in string column

Tags: python, pandas

so if I have a pandas dataframe

```
msg | label
"hello" | 1
"hi!"   | 0
```

I need something that'll duplicate any row ending with [?,.,!] and duplicate the row without the punctuation so the above row would become

```
msg | label
"hello" | 1
"hi!"   | 0
"hi"    | 0
```

after the transformation. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'msg': ["hi!", "hello"], 'label': [0, 1]})

punc = df[df['msg'].str.endswith('?', '.', '!')] # create separate dataframe for punctuations
punc['msg'] = punc['msg'].str[:-1] # remove punctuations
df = pd.concat([df,punc], axis=0) # append the two dataframes
df

     msg  label
0    hi!      0
1  hello      1
0     hi      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the entries in your dataframe which end with `?`, `.` or `!`; strip the punctuation from the end and then join that back to the original dataframe, sorting the index to keep the two versions of strings with punctuation together:

```
punc = df[df['msg'].str.endswith(('?', '.', '!'))].copy()
punc['msg'] = punc['msg'].str.rstrip('?.!')
out = pd.concat([df, punc]).sort_index(kind='stable',ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     msg  |  label
0  hello  |      1
1    hi!  |      0
2     hi  |      0
```

Comment: Better should be `out = pd.concat([df, punc]).sort_index(kind='stable',ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @jezrael good point; that ensures  the duplicates are always kept together. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {"msg": ["hello", "hi!"], "label": [1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a copy of the original df
strip_df = df.copy()

# Remove the unwanted characters from the copy
strip_df.loc[:, "msg"] = strip_df.loc[:, "msg"].str.replace(r"!|\.|\?", "", regex=True)

# Concatenate the original df and the copy
df = pd.concat([df, strip_df])

# Remove duplicates (rows that didn't have the unwanted characters)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```